# HEOS, dreamnucleus - group command return nothing

Tags: c#

I am building a windows C# application to control my Denon Heos speakers and I can get the players, start and stop music etc.

I am using the library from DreamNucleus https://github.com/dreamnucleus/Heos

In my Heos setup I have one receiever and two speakers setup in a stereo pair (group) and when I get the play list I get the receiver and one of the speakers. I actually expect that since the two speakers are groups to one however I get the name of one of the individual speakers not the group name.

I assume I can get the group name via the call to get groups. That sounds logic to me so I have following code in my application.

```
var getGroupsResponse = await _commandProcessor.Execute(new GetGroupsCommand());
if (getGroupsResponse.Success && getGroupsResponse.Payload.Any())
{
   var getGroupInfoResponse = await _commandProcessor.Execute(new GetGroupInfoCommand(getGroupsResponse.Payload.First().Gid));
   if (getGroupInfoResponse.Success)
   {
      // todo
   }
}
```

The variable getGroupsResponse does not contain any groups in the payload. I have checked via debug (breakpoint on the if statement)

Does anybody know if the library is missing any code? The documentation on github does specify that the get groups command is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests where I unpaired my stereo pair I found out that a stereo pair is not considered a group hence no results from the group command because I only had the stereo pair. But once I split the pair and just had them in a group I got a result back.

I also reached out to the author of the documentation for the command line interface @Denon and he confirmed that a stereo pair is hidden from the group command.